# Struts 1.3.8 simple page link without validation

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am working for a while with Struts 1.3.8 and I need to link my new .jsp file and avoid all validation I have in project.

I've got simple code in my loggin.jsp file:

```
 <html:link page="/lookPage">Look</html:link>
```

Now, I want to redirect it from loggin.jsp to another .jsp file with some informations for all vievers, not only logged users.

In my struts-config.xml file I set:

```
<action path="/lookPage" validate="false" name="lookPage">
    <forward name="lookPage" path="lookPage.page" />
</action>
```

and in another xml file my definition of .page name:

```
<definition name="lookPage.page" path="/jsp/common/lookPage.jsp" />
```

Unfortunately I've got error 404 not found.
Can someone help a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only forwarding I use definition of action.

```
<action path="/lookPage" forward="lookPage.page" validate="false"></action>
```

In jsp page use

```
<html:link action="/lookPage">Link</html:link>
```

in web.xml
I have definition of struts servlet.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
.....
```

and mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my link looks like

```
<html:link action="/lookPage.do">Link</html:link>
```

Comment: In this case, I've got error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path [lookPage.page] does not start with a "/" character